# How to give sign + for positive hex numbers in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have positive and negative hex numbers like:

```
-0x30
0x8
```

I want to convert these into strings and then search it in another string. Negative hex numbers keeps the sign while converting into strings, but the problem is with the positive hex. I have these as a dictionary keys, something like:

```
x = {'-0x30': u'array', '0x8': u'local_res0'}
```

Now, my question is how to convert the positive hex numbers in strings with + sign.

I have tried something like:

```
'{0:+}'.format(number)
```

But, it doesn't work as the number is not an integer but a hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "hex" object. Your hex values are strings already.

You can manipulate the string directly, or you could parse it to an integer, then re-convert it to a string of the desired format. Here's a quick version of each:

```
numbers = ['-0x30', '0x8']

reformatted_via_str = [numstr if numstr.startswith('-') else '+'+numstr for numstr in numbers]
reformatted_via_int = [format(num, '+#x') for num in (int(numstr, 16) for numstr in numbers)]
```

Comment: I got that. Thanks so much anyways!

Answer (score 0):

When you say `to convert the positive hex numbers in strings with + sign.`

You mean to `concatenate` between them?

Like so...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
   this is a basic example using Python 3.7.3
'''
import re 

# simple data like the above
data = { hex(-48) : u'array', hex(8) : u'local_res0' }

# output: 
>> { '-0x30' : 'array', '0x8' : 'local_res0' }
#----------------------\n

inverted_negatives = [h3x.replace('-','+') for h3x in data.keys() if re.match('-', h3x)]
# output: 
>> ['+0x30']
#----------------------\n

regex_h3x = r'0x'
replacement = '+0x'
plus_positives = [h3x.replace(regex_h3x, replacement) for h3x in data.keys() if re.match(regex_h3x, h3x)]
# output: 
>> ['+0x8']
#----------------------\n
```

You can also try to convert a `hex(-48) -> str : '-0x30'` and convert it 
using hard cast with `int(str, bytes) -> int` like so...

```
 int(hex(-48), 0)
 # output: 
 -48
 #----------------------\n
```